# Install and publish Laravel package without composer

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php

I want to use this package: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Installation for using OAuth 2.0 in Laravel

I can't install it correctly. First, I cannot update the composer, so I have to change `"minimum-stability": "stable"` to `"minimum-stability": "dev"`. By updating the composer, all my packages are being replaced bij dev versions.

And second, I can not publish my package by typing this command in my terminal: `php artisan config:publish lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel`.

I get this error:

```
php artisan config:publish lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"file_put_contents(\/Applications\/XAMPP\
/xamppfiles\/htdocs\/api-dashboardv2\/app\/storage\/meta\/services.json): failed to
open stream: Permission denied","file":"\/Applications\/XAMPP\/xamppfiles\/htdocs\
/api-dashboardv2\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Filesystem\
/Filesystem.php","line":69}}
```

I tried `chmod -R 777 app`, but  it is unable to change the file mode on app. I am using XAMMP for developing.

Can I install and publish this package without composer or something?

**UPDATE:**

I get the following error now:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\Adapter' not
>   found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api-dashboardv2/vendor/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/src/Storage/FluentAdapter.php
>   on line 18
>   {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class
>   'League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\Adapter' not
>   found","file":"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api-dashboardv2/vendor/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/src/Storage/FluentAdapter.php","line":18}}

And, is it possible to set `"minimum-stability": "dev"` back to `'stable'` and only get the dev version of the OAuth package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned you should be fine by giving it write permission as described in the Docs

```
chmod -R 775 app/storage
```

Note that 775 should be sufficient. Here's a [nice answer](https://serverfault.com/a/144195) pointing out the difference...

---

Regarding the stability config in your `composer.json`

You can define the stability on each package!

```
"lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "@dev"
```

[Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

#### Update

*[The bug has been fixed in the meantime]*

Apparently someone just made very recent changes to the project that broke some things. They are already trying to fix it... [Github Issue](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/issues/227)

Comment: The documentation of this package says: If installation fails set "minimum-stability": "dev" in your composer.json file. And the installation failed. So, yes, I need the dev version.

Comment: Do you have to class in your vendor directory? Should be something like `vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/League/OAuth2/Server/Storage/Adapter.php`

Comment: The directory does exist, but there is no file named Adapter.php. Two files are in there, named Authorization.php and Resource.php. And that is correct. I downloaded the zip file from Github and the same files are in there.

Comment: I am using version 2.1.3 of this package because of I couldn't install the newest version. So, does this bug have affect on my version?

Comment: That's definitely a workaround... Or you could wait a day or too. I'm sure they'll fix it rather quickly

Comment: Maybe it's better to wait a day and get the newest version ;)

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer to show everybody that this question is resolved?

Comment: The question is not resolved. This morning, I installed the package with version number *, so composer installed 2.3.1. for me. So the error what we talking about still exists in this version. About a couple hours or days, I wil try the newest version from Github again. Maybe it works and solve my problem.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. I didn't want to sound demanding. I hope an update of the project fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `chmod -R 777 app/storage` or sufficient write permissions to the folder. As the framework stores and write to the folders within the folder. The documentation does say [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#configuration).

Comment: @Marten You update single packages with composer update <vendor>/<package> and you do not have to update the rest.

Answer (score -1):

did you try:

```
chmod 777 app/storage/meta/services.json
```

it worked for me easily

Comment: Adding these permissions may not solve other permission errors later on. But the documentation say to give write access to the folders as seen [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#configuration)